# How to update Antd's Form Item Input values & content based on a state variable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I've been trying to implement the Google Places API to autofill the fields of a simple address form with Antd, but so far, after have chosen a place, the fields won't populate the way I want.

I am using the package `react-google-autocomplete` successfully to get what I want.

To test things, I have been focusing on just using 1 field, the `city` one.

Right now, my form is decomposed in 2 elements.

**NewForm.tsx**

```
const NewForm = (props: Props) => {
const [form] = Form.useForm();

const formRef = useRef<any>(null);

const onFinish = async (values: any) => {
    const newAddressData: NewAddressInput = {
        name: values.name?.toUpperCase(),
        company: values.company?.toUpperCase(),
        street1: values.street1.toUpperCase(),
        street2: values.street2?.toUpperCase(),
        city: values.city.toUpperCase(),
        state: values.state.toUpperCase(),
        zip: values.zip.toUpperCase(),
        country: values.country.toUpperCase(),
        phone: values.phone,
        notes: values.notes,
    };
    const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo: any) => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
    if (errorInfo.errorFields.length > 0) {
        errorInfo.errorFields.map((field: { errors: string[]; }, index: any) => {
            toast.error(field.errors[0] as string);
        });
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('form values in useEffect', form.getFieldValue('city'));

}, [form]);

console.log('form values', form.getFieldValue('city'));

return (
    <Dashboard>
         <Form
            ref={formRef}
            form={form}
            name="newClientForm"
            labelCol={{ span: 3 }}
            wrapperCol={{ span: 22 }}
            initialValues={{ remember: true }}
            onFinish={onFinish}
            onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
            autoComplete="off"
            className={styles.createClientForm}
            layout="horizontal"
            onValuesChange={(changed, all) => console.log('values change', changed, all)}
            onFieldsChange={(first, second) => console.log('fields change', first, second)}
            fields={[
                {
                    name: 'city',
                    value: form.getFieldValue('city')
                }
            ]}
        >
            <h2>Create a New Client</h2>
            <Divider />
            <CreateAddressFields />
            <Form.Item
                style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
            // wrapperCol={{ offset: 4, span: 16 }}
            >
                <Button
                    type="primary"
                    htmlType="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    </Dashboard>
);
};
```

**CreateAddressFields.tsx**

```
function CreateAddressFields({ }: Props) {
const [foundAddress, setFoundAddress] = useState<NewAddressInput | null>(null);
const [city, setCity] = useState<string | null>(null);

const inputRef = useRef<any>(null);
const options = {
    componentRestrictions: { country: ["ca", "us"] },
    fields: ["address_components", "geometry", "icon", "name"],
    types: ["address"]
};
// inputRef.current.focus();


const { ref, autocompleteRef } = usePlacesWidget({
    apiKey: PLACES_API_KEY,
    onPlaceSelected: (place, inputRef, something) => {     
        console.log('place selected', place);
        const address = place.address_components;
        let { street1, street2, city, state, zip, country }: NewAddressInput = {
            street1: '',
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            zip: '',
            state: '',
            country: ''
        };
        if (address) {
            console.log('going through found address');
            for (const component of address) {
                const type = component.types[0];
                switch (type) {
                    case "street_number":
                        street1 = `${component.long_name} ${street1}`;
                        break;
                    case "route": {
                        street1 += component.short_name;
                        break;
                    }

                    case "postal_code": {
                        zip = `${component.long_name}${zip}`;
                        break;
                    }

                    case "locality":
                        city = `${component.long_name}${city}`;
                        break;

                    case "administrative_area_level_1": {
                        state = `${component.short_name}${state}`;
                        break;
                    }

                    case "country":
                        country = `${component.short_name}${country}`;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            setFoundAddress({ street1, street2, city, state, zip, country });
            console.log('results', { street1, street2, city, state, zip, country });
        }
    },
    options
});

const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    console.log('name', event.target.name);
    const name = event.target.name;
    console.log('value', event.target.value);
    const value = event.target.value;
    setFoundAddress({ ...foundAddress!, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    if (name === 'city') {
        setCity(value);
    }

};
return (
    <>
        <Form.Item
            label="Name: "
            name="name"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your name!' }]}>
            <Input
            // onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
            label="Company: "
            name="company">
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
            label="Street Info 1:"
            name="street1"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your street1!' }]}>
            <Input
                placeholder=''
                ref={(c) => {
                    inputRef.current = c;
                    if (c) ref.current = c.input;
                }}
            // ref={inputRef}
            />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
            label="Street Info 2:"
            name="street2">
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
            label="City:"
            name="city"
            // initialValue={foundAddress?.city ? foundAddress.city : ''}
            // getValueFromEvent={handleChange}
            getValueProps={(v) => {
                return ({ name: 'city', value: v });
            }}
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your city!' }]}>
            <Input
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={city!
                    // ? foundAddress.city : ''
                }
            // placeholder={foundAddress?.city}
            />
        </Form.Item>
        {/* <input
            name={"city"}
            value={foundAddress?.city}
            placeholder={"City"}
            onChange={handleChange}
        /> */}
        <Form.Item
            label="State:"
            name="state"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your state!' }]}>
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
            label="Zip:"
            name="zip"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your zip!' }]}>
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        {/* {countriesList && ( */}
        <Form.Item
            label="Country:"
            name="country"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please choose your country!' }]}>
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        {/* )} */}
        <Form.Item
            label="Phone:"
            name="phone"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your phone number!' }]}>
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
            label="Notes:"
            name="notes">
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
    </>
```

The suggestion is triggered when typing in `street1` field. Once a place is selected, it successfully sets the state variable `foundAddress`. But none of the other fields (in this test case, city) get populated with the selected value.

I've tried quite a few things:

- using the props of the `Form.Item`, such as `initialValue`, `getValueFromEvent`, `getValueProps`.
- adding the props on the `Input` component
- using the props of the `Form` component: `onValuesChange`, `onFieldsChange`, `fields`.
- creating a unique state variable for the `city` field.

The field never gets updated.

On the other hand, if I use a simple `<input>` instead, I tested and got the value showing when the state variable is populated.
Also, if I fill the `placeholder` of the `<Input>`as `placeholder={foundAddress?.city}`, it does work after selecting an address properly as expected.

What am I doing wrong in value handling with this Antd form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update form fields using `form.setFieldValue("key", value)`

Comment: Hahaha...as simple as this. Hours of hair pulling and lack of sleep for that. Thank you.

Comment: It happened to me also, when I first used antd